# FuelUX wizard is not rendered properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, wizard, fuelux

I would like to put a [fuel ux wizard](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard) on my project and to do so I imported the plugins and the css as defined [in this tutorial](https://code.exacttarget.com/devcenter/fuel-ux/getting-started). You can see the result in this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3BVyg?p=preview

Now, why is the previous button so badly rendered? Why I don't get the UI shown by first link? How am I supposed to import the fluelux plugin into my page? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FuelUX.css used in the example you linked to references Bootstrap 2.3.0 in the comments where as the it css in your example shows 2.2.2 therefor different files.

Replacing your first css link with 
  http://fuelcdn.com/fuelux/2.3/css/fuelux.css
will sync you up with what is on the example page.

You'll also note the link does not include -imh. Fuelux-imh is a theme for ExactTarget (the company that created FuelUX). The plain buttons come with the stock css (not '-imh').